# Display BLOB object in Java web project avoiding persistent cross site scripting?

Tags: java, database, security, blob, xss

How do I display data stored as a `BLOB` object in a Java web project and avoid a persistent cross site scripting vulnerability?

The method `respond()` in `ViewDeliveredReportsPage.java` sends un-validated data to a web browser on `line 2775`, which can result in the browser executing malicious code.

```
2773 byte[] barray = new byte[byteLen];
2774 barray = blob.getBytes(1,byteLen);
2775 httpResponse.getOutputStream().write(barray);
2776 } catch (SQLException e) {
2777 logger.error("ERROR onSelectionChanged
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you pass the data to be displayed, you need to escape it. The OWASP ESAPI library seems like it would be a good choice. You can find it here: https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/downloads/list

```
byte[] barray = new byte[byteLen];
barray = blob.getBytes(1,byteLen);
//You'll probably have to convert this to a string first - I am not too
//familiar with Java, but the principal is the same.
String output = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(barray);
httpResponse.getOutputStream().write(output);
} catch (SQLException e) {
logger.error("ERROR onSelectionChanged
```

It's worth reading this cheat sheet: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet